# How to combine elements of a list in threes

Tags: python, zip, list-comprehension, slice

I am able to combine every two elements of a list like this:

```
colors=['green','yellow','red','green','yellow','red']
colors2=[x+y for x,y in zip(colors[0::2],colors[1::2])]
colors2
Out: ['greenyellow','redgreen','yellowed']
```

However, I am unable to combine every three elements of a list:

```
colors3=
[x+y+z for x,y,z in zip(colors[0::3],colors[1::4],colors[2::5])]
colors3
Out: ['greenyellowred']
```

Where are the other three is my slicing misaligned?

Answer (score 0):

This code does the trick had to investigate and trial and error.  The integer to the left of double colons is the low and to the right is the stride.  It makes sense if you think about it and understand how zip works.

```
color3=[x+y+z for x,y,z in zip(color[0::3],color[1::3],color[2::3])]
```